# mb_send_mailがFALSEになる。sendmailのインストール＆設定が必要ですか？

Tags: php, centos, sendmail

**環境**
・PHP7
・CentOS7

---

**現状**
・mb_send_mail実行してもメールを送れない
・FALSEが返ってくる

---

**確認したこと**
・phpinfo()で、mbstringのMultibyte Supportは、enabled
・sendmail_pathは、/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i　となっているが該当ディレクトリなし
・yumでsendmailをインストールした形跡が見当たらない

---

**質問**
・sendmailインストールすればよいかな、と思ったのですが、下記リンク先の設定はすべて必要ですか？
・PHPでmb_send_mail実行したいだけなのですが、それはメールサーバを構築することと同義でですか？
・「sendmail」のホスト名とドメイン名とは何のことですか？

[【CentOS7】sendmail 基本設定](https://www.server-memo.net/server-setting/sendmail/sendmail-setting_centos7.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/sbin/sendmail` コマンドが必要なのであれば、`postfix` に互換コマンドがありますので、postfix をインストールするといいと思います。